# hello, i am tring to create a sorting method that is called from a user menu. java

Tags: java

i am tring to create a sorting method that is called from a user menu(switch loop) then the selection implements boolean parameters (true = ascending, flase = descending). im confused on the boolean aspect

```
Sorting method:

    // Select ascending sort or descending sort based on 
    // passed boolean parameter

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void sortStringArray(){

    //      boolean updown = false;


            System.out.println("Before Sorting: ");
            for(String string : list) {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
            Arrays.sort(list);

            System.out.println("Ascending Sort of String Array, A to Z: ");
                for (String string : list) {
                    System.out.println(string);
                }
                Arrays.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());

            System.out.println("Descending Sort of String Array, Z to A: ");
            for (String string : list) {
                    System.out.println(string);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it with if statements?

For example:

```
boolean check = true;

if (check) {
    Arrays.sort(list);
    System.out.println("Ascending Sort of String Array, A to Z: ");
    for (String string : list) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
} else {
    Arrays.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println("Descending Sort of String Array, Z to A: ");
    for (String string : list) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (check == true) {`? `if (check == false) {`? Wouldn't it be better to recommend the cleaner and more Java standard `if (check) {` and likewise `if (!check) {`

Comment: That's even better. I was trying to give him an idea how he can use if statements.

Comment: ... and there's also the point of your code indentation making it harder to read than it needs to be.

Comment: Can you show me how should the indentation look like?

Comment: Seriously? I'm going to recommend that you Google this as standard style guides are not difficult to find. [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+style+guide+indentation). First 2-3 hits.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will look up some guides and try to better format my examples next time as I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the boolean as an argument to your method. So instead of:

```
public void sortStringArray()
```

It would be:

```
public void sortStringArray(boolean ascending)
```

You can then check against `ascending` to determine which way to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest implementation it should work like this:

```
public void sortStringArray(boolean updown){
        System.out.println("Before Sorting: ");
        print();

        if(updown){
            Arrays.sort(list);
            System.out.println("Ascending Sort of String Array, A to Z: ");  
        } else {
            Arrays.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
            System.out.println("Descending Sort of String Array, Z to A: ");
        }
        print();  
    }

private void print(){
   for (String value: list) {
      System.out.println(value);
   }
}
```